# Gmock - matching structures with more than two vairables

Tags: c++, struct, googletest, matcher, googlemock

Unlike the question in [Gmock - matching structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938233/gmock-matching-structures), I'm wondring how I could create a matcher for a struct with >2 members. Let's say I've got a structure of 8 members, and that MyFun() takes a pointer to a SomeStruct_t as an argument.

```
typedef struct
{
  int data_1;
  int data_2;
  int data_3;
  int data_4;
  int data_5;
  int data_6;
  int data_7;
  int data_8;
} SomeStruct_t;

SomeStruct_t my_struct;

EXPECT_CALL(*myMock, MyFun(MyMatcher(my_struct)));
```

Do you have any suggestions/examples on how MyMatcher should be implemented? Or, could I solve this without using a matcher? I'd like to check each element of my_struct.

Comment: What trouble are you having adapting the answers to the question you linked? It seems pretty straightforward to just add more checks for the additional fields.

Comment: I don't see how I can adapt those answers, hence my question.

Comment: Just provide equal operator for `my_struct`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MATCHER_P(MyMatcher, MyStruct, "arg struct does not match expected struct")
{
  return (arg.data_1 == MyStruct.data_1) && (arg.data_2 == MyStruct.data_2)  &&
    (arg.data_3 == MyStruct.data_3)  && (arg.data_4 == MyStruct.data_4)  &&
    (arg.data_5 == MyStruct.data_5)  && (arg.data_6 == MyStruct.data_6)  &&
    (arg.data_7 == MyStruct.data_7) && (arg.data_8 == MyStruct.data_8);
}
```

This solved my problem. Though it would be nice with more examples in the gmock documentaion.

Answer (score 1):

You own answer is ok, but there is better way to do it. It is good practice to provide stream operator or `PrintTo` function for better readability of gtest logs.

And it is possible to force GTest print better messages for a matcher in case of failure.

```cpp
using testing::AllOf;
using testing::ExplainMatchResult;
using testing::Field;
using testing::Not;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&  out, const SomeStruct_t& data)
{
    return out << '{' 
        << data.data_1 << ','
        << data.data_2 << ','
        << data.data_3 << ','
        << data.data_4 << ','
        << data.data_5 << ','
        << data.data_6 << ','
        << data.data_7 << ','
        << data.data_8 << '}';
}

MATCHER_P(MyMatcher, myStruct, "")
{
    return ExplainMatchResult(
        AllOf(Field("data_1", &SomeStruct_t::data_1, myStruct.data_1),
              Field("data_2", &SomeStruct_t::data_2, myStruct.data_2),
              Field("data_3", &SomeStruct_t::data_3, myStruct.data_3),
              Field("data_4", &SomeStruct_t::data_4, myStruct.data_4),
              Field("data_5", &SomeStruct_t::data_5, myStruct.data_5),
              Field("data_6", &SomeStruct_t::data_6, myStruct.data_6),
              Field("data_7", &SomeStruct_t::data_7, myStruct.data_7),
              Field("data_8", &SomeStruct_t::data_8, myStruct.data_8)),
              arg, result_listener);
}
```

This kind of litle afford pays of a lot later when test detects some problem.

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9rEhsY116)